# sh script to replace IP address from a file with one stored in a text file

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

I have

```
#!/bin/sh
tcpdump -c 1 -eni any host 100.80.1.252 > tcpd.txt
sleep 2
awk 'NR==1{print $9}' tcpd.txt > ip.txt
sleep 2
cat ip.txt
```

output is 
100.70.62.33

Now I want to change every 100.70.x.x address from file1 with one stored in ip.txt file

What i want to achieve:

I have a sh script that is calling some iptables rules (this is the file where i want to modify 100.70.x.x IP)

```
cat set_direct_routing_server_2.sh

#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --source 192.168.219.2 --destination 192.168.219.4/30 -j DNAT --to-destination 100.70.62.21
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --source 100.70.62.21 --destination 100.80.1.252 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.219.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --source 100.70.62.21 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.219.6

ipstables -t nat -L
```

`master.sh` is the script i was talking in first post:

```
#!/bin/sh
tcpdump -c 1 -eni any host 100.80.1.252 > tcpd.txt
sleep 2
awk 'NR==1{print $9}' tcpd.txt > ip.txt
sleep 2
cat ip.txt
sleep 2
sed -i "s/100\.70\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(<ip.txt)/g" set_direct_routing_server_2.sh
cat set_direct_routing_server_2.sh
```

When I call master.sh I have following output.

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
```

listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
    1 packet captured
    2 packets received by filter
    0 packets dropped by kernel
    100.70.62.33
    #!/bin/sh
    iptables -t nat -F

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --source 192.168.219.2 --destination 192.168.219.4/30 -j DNAT --to-destination
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --source  --destination 100.80.1.252 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.219.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --source  -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.219.6

ipstables -t nat -L
```

As you see 100.70.x.x address are only deleted

Comment: You are looking for SED, check the link for examples how to use
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984824/sed-command-in-bash

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash] for a `sh` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s=$(cat ip.txt)
awk -v s="$s"  '{gsub(/100.70.[0-9].{1,3}.[0-9]/, s)}1' file.txt
```

`s=$(cat ip.txt)`  in this variable I store the output of a sub-shell

`-v  s="$s"` here  `-v` receives a shell variable both local and global. in this case and local.

`gsub`   stands for global substitution. It replaces every occurrence

`/100.70.[0-9].{1,3}.[0-9]/`   aki the regular expression to match all ip `100.70. *`

`, s`   this variable has the value of our sub-shell that was created at the beginning and takes it by the `-v` flag of `awk`, which at that moment will print its value.

`1`   Is seen as true and therefore is equivalent to print.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being a little loose on the IP address regular expression, you could use `sed`:

```
sed "s/100\.70\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(<ip.txt)/g" < file1 > output
```

or, with a `sed` that supports `-i`:

```
sed -i "s/100\.70\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(<ip.txt)/g" file1
```

The regular expression to match "100.70.x.x" addresses will match valid IP addresses as well as invalid ones, such as: `100.70.900.678`, as the `[0-9]\{1,3\}` simply says to match between one and three digits.

The replacement text is done within the double-quotes via a special command substitution (`$(< filename)`) that simply reads the contents of the `ip.txt` file.

The `g` flag tells sed to replace every matching instance on each line. If you'll only have one IP address per line, there's no need for the `g` flag.

Comment: Hi Jeff,  sed command is doing the job when is called manually but, added in a .sh script it only deletes 100.70.x.x entries and do not replace them.

Comment: The sed command expects the ip.txt file to be in your current directory..?

Comment: yes, all files and script are in same directory

Comment: How are you calling the script?